# Why did parshuram curse stotras? Why Gita, Vishnu Sahasranama and Chandika Saptashathi among some more are free form all dosha?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, stotra, gita, vishnu-sahasranama, chandipath

Varahi Tantra says that in the age of Kali yuga, most stotras are cursed by Parashurama and hence are ineffective. While listing the ones which are free from this curse and hence suitable during Kali Yuga, it is said, "Gita of the Bhishma Parva, Vishnu Sahasranama of Mahabharata and Chandika Saptashati' (Devi Mahatmyam) are free from all Doshas and grant fruits immediately in Kali Yuga."

Why did Parshurama curse the strotas? Why did he didn't curse others? Should we still practice the cursed strotas and what are the harms otherwise?
What happens if we follow them anyways?

Comment: Where did you get that Varahi Tantra quote?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan [Kamakoti Mandali Blog](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=141&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)
Although this might not be a source along with the guidelines but I read similar things at more than once place.

Comment: Don’t worry, the site only has rules about sources in answers, not sources in questions.

Comment: Thx for posting this question, didn’t know about this clearly before.