# Are mantras cursed not to work in Kali Yuga?

Tags: vedas, mantras, kali-yuga, curse

Are mantras cursed not to work in Kali Yuga?

Is it true that all mantras are cursed and they will not work in kaliyuga?
When invaders attacked India why the mantras were not used to defend if mantras are working?

Comment: This transfers me into a dilemma where there are books which say reading or doing mantra 'jaap' is the best in kaliyug which is referred to everywhere in most puranas.

Comment: Not all mantras were cursed but many were. But the methods by which these curses can be removed are also known from scriptures.

Comment: In [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33427/why-did-parshuram-curse-stotras-why-gita-vishnu-sahasranama-and-chandika-sapta) you will find that Tantra mentions that most Stotras (with the exception of very few) are cursed to be ineffective in Kali Yuga. Mantras also have curses. But probably not all have curses on them.

Answer (score 1):

Mantras, yagya or penance don't work in Kaliyuga. Tulsidas in Ramcharitmanas has clearly said it:-

dhyānu prathama juga makhabidhi dūjēṃ. dvāpara paritōṣata prabhu pūjēṃ.. kali kēvala mala mūla malīnā. pāpa payōnidhi jana mana mīnā..

In the first age, contemplation; in the second age, sacrifice; in the Dvāpara age the Lord is propitiated through worship. This age of Kali, however, is simply corrupt and the root of all impurities, where the mind of man wallows like a fish in the ocean of sin.

nāma kāmataru kāla karālā. sumirata samana sakala jaga jālā.. rāma nāma kali abhimata dātā

In this terrible age the Name alone is the wish-yielding tree, the very thought of which puts an end to all the illusions of the world. The Name ‘ Rāma ’ is the bestower of one's desired object in this age of Kali.

Ramcharitmanas, Baal Kanda, Naam Vandana.